# PHP code is returning HTML entities for special German characters

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I cannot get my PHP 5.3 code to return exactly what I have in my MySQL (5.5) DB.

I'm using jquery-ui-autocomplete (1.9.2, but it did it with 1.8.x as well) to retrieve city names. For example one city is "Heßheim" but PHP is returning "He`&szlig;`heim". The database/table collation was Latin1_general_ci, but changing it to utf8_general_ci did not help. My PHP code:

```
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

if (!is_numeric($term)) {
    $qstring = "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM table WHERE city LIKE '" . $term . "%' ORDER BY city ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($qstring);
    //query the database for entries containing the term

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { //loop through the retrieved values
        //$row['id'] = (int)$row['id'];
        $row['city'] = htmlentities(strip_tags($row['city']));
        $row_set[] = htmlspecialchars_decode($row['city']);
        //build an array
    }
}

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

I've tried everything I could think of to decode the HTML entities, but even the above does not do it. Also the `$row['city'] = htmlentities(strip_tags($row['city']));` has to be there, or it won't return anything for Heßheim.

Testing the script returns this webpage - ["Heddesheim","Heidelberg","Heßheim"] - and the page source looks like this - ["Heddesheim","Heidelberg","He`&szlig;`heim"]. Of course jquery-ui-autocomplete is listing it as He`&szlig;`heim.

Comment: How did you set it to UTF-8?

Comment: Did you both set the connection to UTF-8, and make sure that the data in the database is in UTF-8?

Comment: Try adding this: `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');` before you do anything to the database.

Comment: I currently have the MySQL connection, the database, and table all set to utf8_general_ci.

Comment: I just tried adding the mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); after making the db connection, and now I get ["Heddesheim","Heidelberg","He\u00dfheim"] instead of ["Heddesheim","Heidelberg","He&szlig;heim"].

Comment: If you go into phpMyAdmin, will it display everything correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `html_entity_decode()` instead of `htmlspecialchars_decode`. [PHPMAN](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Also, why are you decoding it if you just encoded it ? The browser will decode the entities while rendering the page, so I think all you need is

```
$row['city'] = htmlentities(strip_tags($row['city']));  
$row_set[] = $row['city'];
```

Comment: OK, when I swap htmlspecialchars_decode with html_entity_decode I get null returned for that particular city (Heßheim). Also, that's the whole confusing thing for me - I thought htmlentities was "decoding" in a sense, and without it jquery-autocomplete is not listing any cities at all.

Comment: Assuming that it's stored properly in the database e.g ("Heßheim" and not "He&szlig;heim"), try it without decoding anything and store it directly. What is the output ? This should work if the file where the script is saved is in UTF-8 without BOM, along with the HTML page (both script and page should be saved in UTF-8 without BOM in physical not just declaring it with code).

Comment: OK, you just went a little beyond my abilities... what is BOM and how do I know if both script and page are saved in UTF-8 without BOM?  Also, that is correct - Heßheim is how it is stored in the DB.  Maybe I should add that I'm using phpMyAdmin to manage the DB, so can it be that phpMyAdmin is decoding the German character when I view it, therefore meaning it's not really stored the way I believe it is?

Comment: phpmyadmin is doing his job alright. Tell me what text editor or IDE are you using and I might be able to help you how to safe the file in a specific encoding scheme.

Comment: I'm using Aptana Studio 3.3.1 (on a Ubuntu 12.04 Notebook). I just checked and there is an option under Edit to Set Encoding, and it's set fot UTF-8.