# PHP json_encode is returning local language characters as html entities. Output needed in unicode

Tags: php, html, mysql, unicode

My php web service uses json_encode to return json data fetched from MySQL database table. The data should be returned in whatever local language as unicode. Instead local characters like hindi/telugu/bengali are displayed as html entities. But output is needed as unicode and NOT html entities.

```
<?php

    //header('Content-Type: text/html;charset: utf8'); //wasted code line

    //Connection and credentials
    $servername = "xxx.yyy.zzz.nnn";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "mydb";

    //variables to store fetched data
    $item[]=array();
    $dataArray[] = array();

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

   //mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn); //wasted code line

   $mytopid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['mytopid']); //get input
   $query = "SELECT  * FROM datamaster where Id > '$mytopid' order by Id desc"; //Now query 

   //mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); //wasted code line

    if ($result=mysql_query($query,$conn)){   
        $rows = mysql_numrows($result);
        $i= 0;
        while ($i < $rows){    
           //fetch data  
           $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

           //wasted code lines
           //$dataArray[$i]["shortid"] = utf8_encode($row['Id']);
           //$dataArray[$i]["shorttitle"] = utf8_encode($row['Title']);

           //reality
           $dataArray[$i]["shortid"] = $row['Id'];
           $dataArray[$i]["shorttitle"] = $row['Title'];
           $i++;
        }
        $item[0]["response"] = 1; 
        $item[1]["matching"] = $rows; 
        $item[2]["events"]=$dataArray;
        echo json_encode($item);
     }else{
        $item[0]["response"] = 0;
    }
    //echo json_encode($item, JSON_HEX_TAG| JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP); //wasted code line

    mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Got Output:
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nEL4.png)

Required Output:
[{"shortid":"5","shorttitle":"\u0c38\u0c32\u0c4d\u0c2e\u0c3e\u0c28\u0c4d\u200c \u0c05\u0c21\u0c3f\u0c17\u0c3f\u0c28\u0c3e \u0c05\u0c35\u0c15\u0c3e\u0c36\u0c2e\u0c3f\u0c35\u0c4d\u0c35\u0c32\u0c47\u0c26\u0c41!"}]

I finally convert it at my client program decode to local language.
The required output is supposed to be the default behaviour of json_encode. Despite most trials per php documentation (see the commented CODE lines that show my trials //wasted code line) the output continues to be in html entities except for English language.

My client programming language does not translate html entities.

Is there a php way to get the required output?
I have tried every possible concept on stack overflow and in php documentation. Now I need help.

[Please refer to my database language settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M5RP.png)

Comment: Does the data in your database already contain HTML entities?

Answer (score 4):

Use `json_encode($item, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`. It will encode multibyte characters literally.
You can get more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php).

Actually it's strange your client side cannot handle escaped characters. What do you use exactly?

Comment: Thank you Wazelin for the prompt reply. I am able to temporarily use html_entity_decode. Not a real solution though. Please refer to the answer I had posted a minute ago and please comment.

Comment: On the client side I am using Swift 3 for iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Thnak you Wazelin for the prompt reply. I had tried the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE approach too earlier. But that output continued to be html entities.

A **temporary** fix to the problem I have incidentally tumbled in to using html_entity_decode.

I changed the code lines in while loop to:

```
     while ($i < $rows){    
       //fetch data  
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

       //reality
       $dataArray[$i]["shortid"] = $row['Id'];

       //handle html entities of local language
       $dataArray[$i]["shorttitle"] = html_entity_decode($row['Title']);
       $i++;
    }
```

That had given the required output. 
But doing this to every single web service is not like an ideal solution. 
Quite strangely the default json_encode behaviour is very elusive in my case.

Comment: Here is a stackoverflow link I came across that helped my temporary solution:                                                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073009/php-code-is-returning-html-entities-for-special-german-characters

Comment: Are you sure that data stored in your DB is not already escaped?

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

There are some options which allows you to encode your data correctly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.